# Ler id clicada e armazenar em uma var para reutilizar

Tags: javascript

Tenho até o momento este código :

```
   document.getElementById('collapseOne').on('click', function(event){  
        event.preventDefault();
        collapseItem(event);
   });
```

porém tenho mais de 1 collapse (no total quatro apenas modificando a numeração no final da id)
e gostaria que o código ficasse apenas nisso.
pensei em criar uma function para ler a id clicada dentro da div pai onde os collapse se encontram mas sem sucesso

```
function clickCollapse(){
  var el = document.getElementById('accordionExample');

  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var idCollapse = "'" + (e.target.id) + "'";
  });
}
```

assim tendo que apenas substituir esta parte do código

```
document.getElementById('collapseOne');
```

pela id capturada neste ultimo bloco exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('idCollapse');
```

porém não funcionou

Comment: Tenta pegar a variável idCollapse sem a concatenação de string, apenas e.target.id, e no momento de pegar ela em document.getElementById(idCollapse); faz sem as aspas

Comment: Se você usar uma classe, e usa o `$(this)` do jQuery, para pegar o attr id pode funcionar. Poste a estrutura do seu colapse também que ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, pelo que vi, você está passando o `event` para uma função que não detalhou o que ela faz, talvez escreveu errado.

Eu acho que uma solução bem mais simples é referenciar todos esses elementos por um seletor "universal", também chamado de [wildcards](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes/) e fazer um `for` e pra declarar que em cada um deles tem esse seu click. Também tem a opção de atributos personalizados, tipo `collapseAttr=id_1` e daí você pega o valor do atributo, mas vamos de `id` já que é a sua necessidade.

```js
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=collapse]') // isso quer dizer "todos elementos que começam com  > collapse <"

function suaFuncao() {
  alert(this.id)
  // sua tratativa aewww
}

for(var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
  elementos[i].onclick = suaFuncao
}
```

```html
<p id="collapse1">click 1</p>
<p id="collapse2">click 2</p>
<p id="collapse3">click 3</p>
<p id="collapse4">click 4</p>
```

Espero ter ajudado!!